# DRBD - 'node1' not defined in your config (for this host) - Error when setting Primary

Tags: hostname, hosts, drbd, pacemaker, corosync

I am getting the following error when trying to set the Primary node for DRBD.

```
'node1' not defined in your config (for this host).
```

I know this is related to DNS/Hostname/Hosts and the config clusterdb.res. I know this because I originally got an error when trying to start clusterdb.res if node1 didn't resolve correctly. So what confuses me is that I can start the clusterdb.res if either use:

*I have used this command on the hosts*

```
hostnamectl set-hostname $(uname -n | sed s/\\..*//)
```

To make the hostname resolve to node1 instead of node1.localdomain

Or add node1.localdomain to the config, either works. But I have tried all combinations and can't seem to get this command to take :

```
drbdadm primary --force node1 && cat /proc/drbd
```

**My Configs**

/etc/drbd.d/clusterdb.res

```
resource clusterdb{
    protocol C;
    meta-disk internal;
    device /dev/drbd0;

startup {
    wfc-timeout 30;
    outdated-wfc-timeout 20;
    degr-wfc-timeout 30;
}

net {
    cram-hmac-alg sha1;
    shared-secret sync_disk;
}


syncer {
    rate 10M;
    al-extents 257;
    on-no-data-accessible io-error;
    verify-alg sha1;
}
on node1 {
    disk /dev/sda3;
    address 192.168.1.216:7788;
}
on node2 {
    disk /dev/sda3;
    address 192.168.1.217:7788;
}
}
```

/etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.216 node1
192.168.1.217 node2
```

/etc/hostname

```
node#
```

[My full write up ATM (wip)](https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2016/04/30/drbd-centos-7-non-lvm-ext4-separate-parition/?preview_id=2850&preview_nonce=b3ee117b89&preview=true)

**Edits :**

```
 [root@node1 ~]# hostname
 node1
 [root@node1 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4      localhost4.localdomain4
 ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6      localhost6.localdomain6
 127.0.1.1     node1
 192.168.1.216 node1
 192.168.1.217 node2
 [root@node1 ~]#
```

Update: I have gotten this to work with LVM following [this guide](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-pcs/html-single/Clusters_from_Scratch/index.html#idm140466757036240) exactly, so I think my issue actually lies with the following lines of code. But for now I think i will stick with LVM since it works, unless somebody else really wants to work on this. [(My working LVM writeup)](https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2016/05/01/drbd-centos-7-lvm/?preview_id=2891&preview_nonce=5c2db1aad9&preview=true)

```
device /dev/drbd0;
```

or

```
 device /dev/drbd0;
```

The reason I say this, is I used the same hosts/hostname/shortname/ip_addr but LVM and it worked, but maybe I missed something the first time, I fixed in my new VM Template (I started from scratch to build LVM)

Comment: Just to be sure - can you please add the output of `hostname`? Also please add the following line to your `/etc/hosts`: `127.0.1.1 node1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the `drbdadm` command correctly. It wants the resource name, where you're giving it a node name.

Try this instead (from node1):

```
drbdadm up clusterdb
drbdadm primary --force clusterdb
```

As a side note, DRBD expects the hostnames in its config to be the same as `uname -n`.

Comment: As soon as I read your answer I understood. Durp thanks!